# Inception retrain error : tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to retrain the iception model using my own classes.

**What I am doing**

I have directory containing images like

- Water Glass
- Water Bottle
- Person
- Chair
- .......

I run following command

```
`python ~/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py \
--bottleneck_dir=/tmp/bottlenecks_new \
--output_graph= output/retrained_graph.pb \
--output_labels= output/retrained_labels.txt \
--image_dir  ~/newimage_dir \
--how_many_training_steps 10000 \
--random_crop=8  \
--random_scale=8 \
--random_brightness=8 \
--train_batch_size=64`
```

**Results**

I got network trained with test accuracy of 94.6 % with an error.

**Traceback**

```
`Final test accuracy = 94.6% (N=613)
Converted 2 variables to const ops.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hannan/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 1061, in <module> tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/home/hannan/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 902, in main
    f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 98, in write self._prewrite_check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 84, in _prewrite_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), compat.as_bytes(self.__mode), status)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__
    self.gen.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError
`
```

**What I have tried**

I have uninstall the tensorflow and installed again from sources, working fine. I have searched about the error, only thing I have understand is error I have encountered is due to some un initialization of variables. But from stacktrace I am not able to resolve the error.

Comment: Is your disk out of space by any chance? Looks like it's an IO error of some kind. Maybe check file/folder permissions if disk space is fine?

Comment: I have a lot disk space free. It's working fine, I have tried two or three time before. Now it's throwing an error.

Comment: I solved the issue by not providing the output directory. There is some permission error.