# Tensorflow retrain.py tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, deep-learning

I tried to run below command to do retain:

```
python tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py --image_dir ~/flower_photos --output_graph tf_output --output_labels tf_output
```

Then I got this error:

```
2017-04-21 00:44:15.386870: Step 3999: Validation accuracy = 95.0% (N=100)
Final test accuracy = 91.4% (N=385)
Converted 2 variables to const ops.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 1062, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/home/demo/anaconda3/envs/tfv1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 903, in main
    f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
  File "/home/demo/anaconda3/envs/tfv1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 98, in write
    self._prewrite_check()
  File "/home/demo/anaconda3/envs/tfv1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 84, in _prewrite_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), compat.as_bytes(self.__mode), status)
  File "/home/demo/anaconda3/envs/tfv1/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/home/demo/anaconda3/envs/tfv1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: tf_output
```

Upon searching, I found this thread and I did exactly what they said by removing output path and it worked

[Inception retrain error : tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42130293/inception-retrain-error-tensorflow-python-framework-errors-impl-failedprecondi)

However, my question is why? I have permission to the folder and space. I tried to move the folder to everywhere /tf_output, tensorflow/tf_output, /home/demo/tf_output and make sure it has demo user owner with 777 recursively.

I still got the same error. So is the retrain.py hardcoded somewhere pointing to /tmp only for output? How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had this problem too. The trick is to specify *filenames* for the flags `--output_labels` and `--output_graph`.

So using your example above, try this:

`python tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py --image_dir ~/flower_photos --output_graph tf_output/output_graph.pb --output_labels tf_output/retrained_labels.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I responded on the original thread. I tried to reproduce this issue locally and see what might be going on and seems like as long as the output directory exists it should work. Could you share some more details on what your setup is? i.e. what platform (linux / windows / mac) are your running on and what version of TF are you using?

Comment: I am using Tensorflow 1.0 on Ubuntu 14. I am using my user account with sudo. By doing mkdir from any other folder, it works in Linux. So TF must be doing something not right causing permission issues.

Comment: I see.. did the answer above mine help though? i.e. mentioning the filenames and not just the directory? I have the same setup as yours and that seemed to work for me.